# Can't call a function from an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an window that is a sort of dashboard. Inside that dashboard i have an iframe that acts as a message centre for sending emails to users in the system.

What i am trying to make:

A drop down box that adds a recipient of the email to a text field when clicked in the drop down box.

My current code:

function in messages.js that outputs the users email as a test

```
function mountRecipient(user_email){
    window.parent.console.log(user_email);
}
```

php that builds the `<option>` tags in the `<select>` tag. This is inside the iframe that holds the form for sending emails

```
function userDropDown() {
    $dbConn = getConnection();
    $sqlRequestUserList = "SELECT * FROM academy_user";
    $user_list = $dbConn->query($sqlRequestUserList);

    foreach ($user_list as $value) {
        printf('<option onClick="mountRecipient(\'%s\');">%s %s: %s</option>', $value['user_email'], $value['f_name'], $value['l_name'], $value['user_email']);
    }

}
```

for some reason, when clicking the drop down item, the onclick event doesn't happen. If i type `mountRecipient(test)` into the chrome console then i get 'test' back from the script.

Why is the onclick event not firing?

(I tried to format the code but it wouldn't work, sorry)

Comment: It could be a chrome security issue.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You can't use events on `<option>` cross browser. Many don't support it

Comment: @Jodast im using Opera which uses Chromium. There's a warning in console but i don't think it's linked to this.

Comment: @charlietfl What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: As mentioned in answer below... change event on `<select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a change event listener to the select where you have added the options (you will need use/give your select a class and replace **select** in my code with your class). So when a user selects any option it will trigger this event. Then within the function itself it simply sends the selected value to your function.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select')[0].addEventListener("change", function() {
     mountRecipient(this.children[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Comment: Modern best practices is to use `addEventListener` over `on-xx` methods

Answer (score 0):

Add parent. if it is on the same domain!

```
onClick="parent.mountRecipient(\'%s\');"
```

Use onClick in select